# Create relationship between a new neo4j Node and an already existing one in Java

Tags: java, neo4j

I am using Java API for Neo4j embedded db.

While saving an instance as a `Node` and I would like to create a `Relationship` from it to another node, that I have no reference other than a property (id/key).

As I understand it, if I'd have the two nodes I would just use:

```
nodeBeingSavedSeparately.createRelationshipTo(
            nodeToHaveRelationshipTo,
            RELATIONSHIP_TYPE
);
```

But I am just adding a new node and I would like to have the relationship with another already existing node, not to create a new node.

Is it possible to get the right instance of `Node` from the database and use it in that method? *Something like:*

```
nodeBeingSavedSeparately.createRelationshipTo(
            getNodeByProperty("idPropertyOfTheNodeToHaveRelationshipTo"), 
            RELATIONSHIP_TYPE
);
```

I found out, that there is a `getNodeById(long);` method, but there is no `Node.setId(long);` method. How do I set/get the right reference for the relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either [findNode](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/GraphDatabaseService.html#findNode-org.neo4j.graphdb.Label-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) or [findNodes](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/GraphDatabaseService.html#findNodes-org.neo4j.graphdb.Label-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) in [GraphDataBaseService](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/javadocs/index.html?org/neo4j/graphdb/GraphDatabaseService.html) to get the existing node.

Comment: I am creating a node of a user `Node node = createNode(); node.setProperty("id", "john"); node.addLabel(Label.label("users"));` and then in another transaction trying to find it by `findNode(Label.label("users"), "id", "john");` but it ends unsuccesful. What am I doing wrong, please?

Comment: I've just changed it to search by using another property and it seems to work. Is the property name `id` reserved?

Comment: `findNode` can throw a MultipleFoundException if there are multiple matching nodes. Is that what is happening?

Comment: Yes, it was indeed trowing the `MultipleFoundException`. I tried to come up with a new `id` and finally found out the old `Nodes` were not getting deleted by the `shutdown()` as I initially thought. Now I cycle through all the existing notes and `delete()` them to get a clean db. Thank you for all your help!